# InputMismatchException after checking with hasNext

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm using a `Scanner` to control input (which comes 1 line at a time) to my program. First, I check the line to see which command it matches. Then, I use Scanner's `next` to go through the line and capture or skip the parts of the input I want (I could use regex capture groups, but I prefer to do it manually.)
I use `next` instead of `skip` even for groups I don't care about because I want to be sure the section of input still *matches* even if I don't care what it is, and `skip` will just silently ignore it if it doesn't match.

The problem is that even after checking for a certain pattern, I get an InputMismatchException when I try to `next` past it.

```
String phone = "(1\\W?)?(\\d{3}|\\(\\d{3}\\))?\\W?\\d{3}\\W?\\d{4}";
String strline = "add 1112223333 matt";
Scanner line = new Scanner(strline).useDelimiter("\n");
String addPat = "(?i)add\\s+" + phone + "\\s+.+";
if (line.hasNext(addPat)) {
    line.next("(?i)add\\s+");                         //InputMismatchException thrown here
    String number = line.next(phone);
}
```

Even the simplified case fails:

```
if (line.hasNext("(?i)add\\s+.+")) {
    line.next("(?i)add\\s+");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A short answer:

Use:

```
line.findInLine("^" + "(?i)add\\s+");
```

instead of:

```
line.next("(?i)add\\s+");
```

---

A long answer:
If you dig into documentation od [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.util.regex.Pattern)) you will find this definition:

> A Scanner breaks its input into **tokens** using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The **resulting tokens** may then be converted into values of different types using the various **next methods**.

In other words:

- Each `nextXXXXX` method parses **exactly one token**.
- The token is a text fragment that is surrounded by two delimiters

Since you are using "\n" as a delimiter, then there is only one token in the input string: "add 1112223333 matt" - the whole string.

This token matches the pattern: `addPat = "(?i)add\\s+" + phone + "\\s+.+";`

But this token doesn't match the pattern: `"(?i)add\\s+"` and the exception is thrown.
Use `Scanner#findInLine` or `Scanner#findWithinHorizon` methods - these methods ignore delimiters and can parse only a part of the token.

Comment: The doc for scanner says `findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile(pattern, horizon))`, is that a typo? findWithinHorizon also has an overload of (Pattern, int). Pattern.compile does have an overload for a String and an int but the int is supposed to be an or of pattern options, not a distance. Also, if I don't know how long the match will be, how can I compute the horizon to use without the risk of a "clip" as described by the doc. I want to use findWithinHorizon instead of findInLine so that it doesn't match "BADTERM add [...]"